# Does $\operatorname{arcsec}(x) = 1 /\arccos(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Does $\operatorname{arcsec}(x) = 1 /\arccos(x)$? I have looked in a few books and Google'd it but I am not finding my answer.

Comment: Go to http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=d08726019e4a2a15cb1d49092e4d0522 and input log10(tan(x) + sec(x)) as your fuction.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsecant

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions

Comment: Remember that arcsec delivers an *angle* as its value. Ordinarily, it makes no sense to take the reciprocal of an angle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. If you [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sec%5E-1%28x%29+cos%5E-1%28x%29) $\sec^{-1}(x) \cdot \cos^{-1}(x)$, you get:

[image: -2 to 2]
[image: -15 to 15]

You can clearly see that it *isn't* $1$.

Answer (score 29):

If $\sec^{-1} x = \theta$, then $x = \sec\theta$. This means $\frac1x = \cos\theta$, so $\cos^{-1}\frac1x = \theta$. So your equation is wrong; the correct statement is $$\boxed{\sec^{-1} x = \cos^{-1}\tfrac1x}$$

Comment: $$(\sec x)^{-1} = (\cos x)^1 \\ \sec^{-1} x = \cos^{-1} x^{-1}$$ it’s kinda satisfying . . . feels like the negative ones cancel each other out

Answer (score 14):

Actually it's: $$\operatorname{arcsec}(x)=\arccos(1/x).$$

Answer (score 5):

No. It is not. If you look at the definitions

$$y=\frac{1}{\cos x}$$

and then we solve for the x

$$\frac{1}{y}=\cos x$$

$$\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{y}\right) = x$$

and replace $x$ and $y$ to find the inverse

$$y=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

Comment: Careful, $\cos^{-1}(\cos(x)) \neq x$ in some cases.

Answer (score 5):

It is straight forward, let $$\sec^{-1}(x)=\alpha$$ $$\implies \sec\alpha=x$$ $$\implies \frac{1}{\cos \alpha}=x$$$$\implies \cos \alpha=\frac{1}{x}$$ $$\implies \alpha=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ Substituting the value $\alpha=sec^{-1}(x)$, we get $$\bbox[4pt, border:1px solid blue;]{\color{red}{\sec^{-1}(x)=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}}$$

Answer (score 3):

No, it is false.
Probably you meant $\operatorname{arcsec}(x)=\arccos(1/x)$, which is true.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't. [Draw](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arcsec%20x%20arccos%20x&dataset=)
$$\text{arcsec} x\arccos x$$

Comment: Please avoid link only answers and add a plot if you are telling the OP to test his theory by graphing.

Answer (score 1):

**No, they are not equal. Here is why.**

We can look at an algebraic approach to arcsec and arccos first:

Arccos(*x*) = *y*
Cos(*y*) = *x*
1/sec(*y*) = *x*
Sec(*y*) = 1/*x*
*y* = arcsec(1/*x*)

Now, we have established that
Arccos(*x*) = y = arcsec(1/*x*),
Thus, arccos(*x*) = arcsec(1/*x*)
And we have got a neat algebraic proof.

Conversely, we can do the reverse by substituting cos for sec in the above equations to get arcsec(*x*) = arccos(1/*x*)

Take a graphing calculator, you can substitute the values, and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7DPW.jpg) is the image of the graph

Lastly, the longest side of a triangle is 1/cos(x) = y, and since y is not equal to sec(y), the above equation in the question is wrong ( 1/cos(x) is not sec(y), and 1/arccos(x) is not arcsec(x) ).